# how do I add a hour to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, strtotime

in php how do I add a hour to

```
$newdatetime = $olddatetime(strtotime("+1 hour"));
// this is the format of $olddatetime 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I already have the hour difference in the timezones I know its with the strtotime function but I couldn't get it formatted right to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", (strtotime($olddatetime." +1 hour")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php) objects:

```
$newdatetime = new DateTime($olddatetime);
$newdatetime->modify('+1 hour');

echo $newdatetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // or whatever output format you want
```

Comment: this is what I got when I tried that. Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: Can you describe what `$olddatetime` is? Post the results of `var_dump($olddatetime)` in your question.

Comment: this is the format of $olddatetime 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: In your question, you're using $olddatetime as a function. You can't call "0000-00-00 00:00:00" as a function.

Comment: I am just looking to add a hour to the 0000-00-00 00:00:00 I realize it doesn't work... I appreciate your time sir :)

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. Do you mean that if you have a date, for instance, `2013-01-01 05:00:00`, you wish to add an hour so that it becomes `2013-01-01 06:00:00` ? Either way, your exception tells me that `$olddatetime` is not a string but something else.

Comment: This worked Balaji Kandasamy knew wht I meant sry for the confusion and thank you very much for your effort... date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", (strtotime($olddatetime." +1 hour")));

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code,

```
    $olddatetime = "2014-03-07 10:00:00"; // Requested format
    $newdatetime = (strtotime($olddatetime."+1 hour")); // add one hour
    $newdatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $newdatetime); // New date time
    echo $newdatetime;exit; // Print it
```